# How to print the FontResourceDir with GhostScript (gs)?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I need my script to be able to figure out, where the `Fontmap.GS` resides in a given GhostScript installation -- so that it can be modified.

I used to rely on the output of `gs -h` for this, but the format of that changed between versions -- and was clumsy to begin with.

I'm quite certain, gs can be asked to print it (to stdout) neatly, but I don't know PostScript, unfortunately. I tried:

```
%!
FontResourceDir ==
```

which simply does not work: `Error: /undefined in FontResourceDir`. I'm sure, I'm very close to the solution -- please, help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ghostscript to find the location of its Resource files. `Fontmap.GS` appears to be in the `/Init` subdirectory of the Resources.

```
/Font /Category findresource
begin
    / 128 string ResourceFileName =
  % ^ 
  % | n.b. this is SLASH followed by SPACE. 
  %   We're feeding an "empty" name to ResourceFileName
end
```

This prints (for me): `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.06/Resource/Font/`

So, this pipe command should do the trick (until it changes again!)

```
echo /Font /Category findresource begin / 128 string ResourceFileName = | \
gsnd -q - | \
sed 's/Font\/$/Init\/Fontmap.GS/'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is usable. I'd still prefer some method of finding Fontmap.GS itself -- there may be hairier installations, I suppose, where the file is in a different location relative to the Font/
But this may be good enough.